# Golang JSON array of different types reflection: float64 vs int64

Tags: json, reflection, go

Consider this simple example:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "reflect"
)

var args = `[1, 2.5, "aaa", true, false]`

func main() {
    var x []interface{}
    err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(args), &x)

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("%s", err.Error())
        panic(fmt.Sprintf("%s", err.Error()))
    }

    for _, arg := range x {
        t := reflect.TypeOf(arg).Kind().String()
        v := reflect.ValueOf(arg)

        if t == "int64" {
            fmt.Printf("int64 %v\n", v.Int())
        }

        if t == "float64" {
            fmt.Printf("float64 %v\n", v.Float())
        }

        if t == "string" {
            fmt.Printf("string %v\n", v.String())
        }

        if t == "bool" {
            fmt.Printf("bool %v\n", v.Bool())
        }
    }
}
```

The program outputs:

```
float64 1
float64 2.5
string aaa
bool true
bool false
```

As you can see, my input is a valid JSON which represents an array with five items:

```
- integer
- floating point number
- string
- boolean
- boolean
```

When I unmarshal the valid JSON string into []interface{} and try to check the types with reflection, the integer value from JSON has a type of float64. Any idea why? Is this expected behaviour?

Comment: If you have a specific structure to your JSON then you'd normally use a type (a `struct` likely) that encapsulates that structure instead of using `interface{}`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is documented behavior of `Unmarshal`. All numbers are unmarshaled into float64.

> To unmarshal JSON into an interface value, Unmarshal stores one of these in the interface value:
>
> - bool, for JSON booleans
> - float64, for JSON numbers
> - string, for JSON strings
> - []interface{}, for JSON arrays
> - map[string]interface{}, for JSON objects
> - nil for JSON null

This is because JSON does not have integers, every number in JSON is defined to be a 64 bit floating point.

Answer (score 3):

This is the default behaviour of the JSON decoder. You can change it to output [`json.Number`](http://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Number) instead by using the [`UseNumber`](http://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Decoder.UseNumber) method.